# 'save link as' / 'open with' / 'launch application' window

Tags: firefox, launcher, downloads, download-manager

When I want to open any file or even when I want to do "save link as" in mozilla there is a pop up window with the title launch application which I should choose an application to open that file. What is it? And how I can configure it to not open for mozilla or if it is not possible how to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As discussed in the comments, it turned out the real issue was somewhere else - I may try to integrate the useful part here.*

---

It is a dialog window of firefox asking you which application to use to open a speciffic kind of file.
The choice will be saved for that file type,
but it will ask for each file type at the first use.

Comment: How can I disable it?

Comment: You mean to not open programs for files?

Comment: No. But when I want to download adobe from its site there are some options that are unable to download that. I just need mozilla to download it with its downloader.(thanks for your replys)

Comment: Oh, if it's about this special case, the problem may be very different (an X-Y-problem). So you want to download and run a downloader for some adobe software? The only step where firefox could help would be downloading the downloader program, and you run it?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve - eg something like "install Adobe Foo version 42.e"?

Comment: sites like adobe don't let downloaders to download their files. Only browsers can do that. But How can I choose the browser as a way to download that file?

Comment: Normally, "Save Llink As..." in the context menu should work. Does it work on other links for you? Try to save the question page using Save link as... on  the question title.

Comment: I think your link may be special or somehow broken or non-standard at least. I have never seen that Save link as... does not work...

Comment: The save link as open that launch application box that I should choose a program.

Comment: You mean, if used on the question title?

Comment: this is the link http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Ah, the link on that yellow button? That's very special indeed - technically, it's not even a link! On that page, if I choose `apt` format to the left, the software center opens... strange. Now I see what you mean. Do you have the problem on any other links?

Comment: I haven't faced the same problem yet.

Comment: Ok, so it's more or less speciffic to downloading software in packages from Adobe - but part of the issue is in firefox, or some firefox extension from ubuntu. The special Adobe link makes it just harder to understand and solve. _Now we have found the **real problem** we want to solve. And can start looking for a **solution**!_ :)

Comment: :) Yeah. You are right.

Comment: It seems it is possible to download it from software centre. Thanks a lot for your helps. Anyway if you find a solution to this problem, I would be happy to here that.

Comment: I have my own issue to debug for now - rewrite/edit the question and title if you like. By the way, are you sure you need the absolute latest flash plugin version? Did you try `adobe-flashplugin` from the Ubuntu partner repository?

Comment: Oh, that version in software center is exactly the one I just asked - the one I use. And I was thinking you try hard to get the newest version - the really absolutely newest version! So, another X-Y-problem! Take a look at that - can help to save lots of your time! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem